# Jquery POST Ajax Return null data in wordpress

Tags: plugins, ajax, javascript, jquery

I really need help on this one. I've been looking at it for hours and been getting nowehere. I am working with ajax in WordPress and this is kind of my first time doing so.

It's always return null data

**This is Jquery Code:**

```
<script>
  (function($){

    $(document).ready(function(){
      
      $(document).on('change', '#myform', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var data = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
          url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
          data: {action:'myaction', data:data},
          type: 'post',
          success: function(result) {
            $('.products').html(result);
          },
          error: function(result) {
            console.warn(result)
          },
        });

      });
    });
  })(jQuery);
</script>
```

**And this is my PHP Code to get my data:**

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_myaction', 'myaction' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_myaction', 'myaction' );

    function myaction() {
          $colors= $_POST['color']; 
        
          var_dump($colors);
    }
```

**HTML CODE:**

```
<form id="myform">
     <select name="color">
          <option type="checkbox" id="widget-color" value="1">blue</option>
          <option type="checkbox" id="widget-color" value="2">red</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

when I do var dump I just see null data so how can fix the problem, please?

[image: Image from console]

Comment: Can you share the code for the form this is associated with? There could be an issue with the form if the 'color' parameter is the only one returning null.

Comment: is your AJAX handler incomplete? I'm not seeing the function or the add_action calls? Also is there a reason you used the older API instead of the current AJAX API aka the REST API? You'd get pretty URLs and human readable error messages when it goes wrong instead of `0` or `null`

Comment: Oh dear, it looks like you didn't use the old `admin-ajax.php` at all and you've put an `ajax.php` file in your theme/plugin, you should never do this under any circumstances. Never make direct requests to PHP files in your theme or plugin, it's a major security issue and can lead to problems like this.

Comment: @grzybowski1911 I shared the code and you check, please?, thanks

Comment: @TomJNowell The ajax handler is already compelete and i shared the code can you check again sir? thanks,, when i do the jquery from on('change') to on('submit') its work well but i want it be after change not submit data

Comment: @TomJNowell My project its an widget and the user can filter products by color so after the user select something that data go to my ajax.php in plugin file and it's filtering the data and display the products

Comment: it shouldn't go to an `ajax.php` that's a security problem and a maintenance issue. It will also cause problems by crashing the moment you try to use a WordPress function. Avoid at all costs. Instead use a REST API endpoint ( WP Handbook: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/, REST API in 2 minutes: https://tomjn.com/2017/01/23/writing-wp-rest-api-endpoint-2-minutes/ ), all that data is already available via prebuilt endpoints/URL already, e.g. tags are at example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/tags, posts, categories, etc and there'll be one for products

Comment: @TomJNowell thank you sir.